# Heroku Laravel SQLite missing

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I'm using Heroku to deploy a Laravel application. Everything seems to be working but I can't connect to my SQLite database:

[image]

I tried to install SQLite by running

```
heroku run apt-get install php7.0-sqlite
```

but this didn't work:

[image]

Then I read a post where it mentioned installing SQLite via `composer.json`, so I tried this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "ext-pdo_sqlite": "*"
},
```

but when I run `composer update` I got this error:

[image]

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: I am going to go ahead and ask you this have you install pdo_sqliet extension?

Comment: i already mention that i can't install

Comment: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/118/setting-up-the-sqlite-database-driver follow this

Comment: its already configured and working in local problem is that it can't run in heroku Read my question properly first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach of requiring `ext-pdo_sqlite` via Composer [should work on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions). Have you updated `composer.lock` as well? You must do this *locally*, then commit your changes, and `git push` to Heroku again. Running `heroku run composer update` won't work as expected due to Heroku's [ephemeral filesytem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

Because of this filesystem SQLite usually isn't a good choice of database on Heroku. Anything you write to disk will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting).

I strongly suggest moving to a production grade client-server database instead. Heroku [supports many data stores](https://elements.heroku.com/addons). [Its own PostgreSQL offering](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) is usually a good place to start.